# Getting transparent UIButton after applying gradient

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I am learning Swift by trying to develop an app.I want to design a button by adding gradient layer, but the problem is it doesn't appear on the screen. It does its function when I clicked where it should appear tho.

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(red: Int, green: Int, blue: Int) {
        assert(red >= 0 && red <= 255, "Invalid red component")
        assert(green >= 0 && green <= 255, "Invalid green component")
        assert(blue >= 0 && blue <= 255, "Invalid blue component")

        self.init(red: CGFloat(red) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(green) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(blue) / 255.0, alpha: 1.0)
}

convenience init(rgb: Int) {
    self.init(
        red: (rgb >> 16) & 0xFF,
        green: (rgb >> 8) & 0xFF,
        blue: rgb & 0xFF
    )
}
```

}

```
extension UIButton
{
    func applyGradient(colors: [CGColor])
{
       let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
       gradientLayer.colors = colors
       gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
       gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
       gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds
       self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
}

lazy var loginButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    let color1 = UIColor(red: 26, green: 41, blue: 128)
    let color2 = UIColor(red: 38, green: 208, blue: 206)
    button.applyGradient(colors: [color1.cgColor, color2.cgColor]) 
    button.setTitle("Log in", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    button.setTitleColor(.black, for: .normal)

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleButtonLogin), for: .touchUpInside)

    return button
}()
```

Actually, it should say Log in(white color) with blue to green gradient layer. If I set the log in title color to black. I can see it when I run the code.

Comment: You might want to add a size (well, a frame) to your `loginButton` before applying the gradient. Because `gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds`, it should be 0,0,0,0, so you won't see the gradient layer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only miss the frame

```
loginButton.frame = self.view.frame
self.view.addSubview(loginButton) 
loginButton.applyGradient(colors: [UIColor.red.cgColor,UIColor.blue.cgColor])
```

//

Also change this line

```
self.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

to

```
self.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
```

as not to hide the title of the button

//

[image]